# overwrite a variable through the select value

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid

*I need to multiply a number with the values 1 till 64.
I want to make this better by just selecting the number through a given selection, but somehow it only takes the first value of my selection. What is wrong here?*

```
<body>
<h1>some calculation</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function times(wert) {
        var j = document.getElementById('number').value;
        return Math.pow(j, wert);
    };
</script>
<select id="number" style="margin:40px;">
<option value="1">1=x</option>
<option value="2">2=x</option>
<option value="3">3=x</option>
<option value="4">4=x</option>
</select>
<table border="1mm">
  <tbody><tr><th>x</th><th>2*x</th>
    <script language="javascript">
        for (var i =0; i <= 64; i++) {
        out = "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + times(i)+ "</td></tr>"
        document.write(out) ;
        } 
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The times function is being called once, only as the page writes. Try encapsulating the part that calls the function into the onchange event of the "number" node. I would append the answers to the table rather than document.write them. Try this out:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function times(wert) {
        var j = document.getElementById('number').value;
        return Math.pow(j, wert);
    };
    function doCalc(){
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="<tr><th>x</th><th>2*x</th></tr>";
        for (var i =0; i <= 64; i++) {
            out = "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + times(i)+ "</td></tr>"
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += out;
        }
    }
</script>
<head>
<body>
<select id="number" style="margin:40px;" onchange="doCalc()">
<option value="0">0=x</option>
<option value="1">1=x</option>
<option value="2">2=x</option>
<option value="3">3=x</option>
<option value="4">4=x</option>
</select>
<table border="1mm">
  <tbody id="output">
      <tr><th>x</th><th>2*x</th></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Two Issues: ***1.*** `out` was never declared. Not sure if that will matter but you may want to consider adding `var out = "";` before the `for` loop. ***2.*** The statement `out = "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + times(i)+ "</td></tr>"` has no terminating semicolon `;`.

Comment: @War10ck, I don't even remember pressing F7.